# Set the size of Collapsible column menu in Vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin

I have a table with huge set of columns, as I prefer to show only those columns that are important and rest is left to the user, if the user wishes to see other columns he selects those from collapsible menu.

I have JSP in which Vaadin layout is embedded via Iframe. As I have said there are huge no of columns(>20) when ever I click on collapsible icon, I get a menu which is larger than the height of the `Iframe` and hence I am not able to select the columns which is beyond the Iframe size(though scrolls appear I am not able to select the columns) say if the size of IFrame is `100px` then the size of column collapsible menu is `120PX` I am not able to select all those columns that are appearing after 100px. I have tried setting the size using the following CSS

```
.v-contextmenu .gwt-MenuBar{

    max-height: 60%;
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following CSS settings and it seems to work fine with no issues.

```
.v-contextmenu .gwt-MenuBar{

width:auto !important;
height:400px !important;
overflow-y: auto !important;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

If in case, you are not able to select the last item in the collapsible menu place the above CSS in Styles.css under your theme.